Etwas fällt auf etwas: Akkusativ oder Dativ
ChatGPT meint, dass folgender Satz richtig ist:

Der Schnee fällt auf den Bergen.

Meines Erachtens handelt er aber von einer Richtung, dementsprechend wäre es richtig, den Akkusativ zu benutzen (auf ist eine „Wechselpräposition").

Der Schnee fällt auf die Berge

aber

Der Schnee liegt auf den Bergen

Habe ich etwas mit den Wechselpräpositionen verwechselt?  Oder sollte ich ChatGPT nicht vertrauen?  Ich benutze das Programm gelegentlich, um sprachliche Zweifelsfälle zu lösen oder Texte zu überprüfen.

"Oder sollte ich ChatGPT nicht vertrauen?" Antwort: Nein!

"Der Schnee fällt auf die Berge." (nicht "Bergen") Bitte etwas mehr Kontext ergänzen: Was war die Frage/Aufgabe für ChatGPT? In bestimmten Fällen könnte auch "Der Schnee fällt auf den Bergen." richtig sein. (Auf den Bergen fällt Schnee, im Tal noch nicht.)

Es war ein Satz aus einem Text, den ich CGPT korrigieren.  Viel mehr Kontext gibt es nicht: etwas wie „Es ist Dezember.  Der Schnee fällt auf den/die Berge(n)."

Ich habe es auf „auf die Berge" geändert

In einem Wetterbericht geht es darum, wo es Niederschlag gibt und nicht darum, wo der Niederschlag hinfällt. Daher wird man in einem Wetterbericht eher etwas wie Schnee fällt auf den Bergen lesen.

Wenn auf den Bergen Schnee fällt, dann fällt auch Schnee auf die Berge - außer dort, wo sie überbaut sind.
Die Beobachtung, dass der Dativ hier einen Ort des Schneefalls angibt und der Akkusativ die Richtung, ist richtig.
Verwendet man Dativ, so spricht man von einem Ort an dem es schneit. Verwendet man Akkusativ, so bezieht man sich auf den Gegenstand (oder die Person) auf die der Schnee fällt.
Beim Wetter bezieht man sich im Allgemeinen auf den Ort, an dem dieses Wetter herrscht - auch wenn das Resultat bei Schneefall oder auch Regen natürlich ist, dass der Niederschlag den Boden erreicht.

Zugegebenermaßen etwas spitzfindig, aber es könnte auch auf den Bergen Schnee fallen, der aber schon getaut ist, wenn er den Boden erreicht. Dann fällt auf den Bergen Schnee, aber er fällt nicht auf die Berge.

@Rha haha, ja :) Den Gedanken hatte ich, zugegebenermaßen, auch. Hatte ihn aus dieser Antwort aber wieder herauseditiert, da er mir zu sehr vom Hauptpunkt ablenkt.
